# Enable "watch episode" feature with google structured data

Tags: web, seo, structured-data

How can I list my webpage in the “Watch now” feature in a Google search.

I have already added a lot of structured data, but unfortunately my streaming service still does not appear.
Webpage:
https://www.srf.ch/play/tv/der-bestatter/video/phoenix-aus-der-asche-staffel-7-folge-6?urn=urn:srf:video:5da1d3d0-e445-447e-a67c-33dd10186f4c

My structured data:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "TVEpisode",
  "@id": "/tv/der-bestatter/video/phoenix-aus-der-asche-staffel-7-folge-6?urn=urn:srf:video:5da1d3d0-e445-447e-a67c-33dd10186f4c",
  "name": "Phönix aus der Asche (Staffel 7, Folge 6)",
  "abstract": "Furioses Finale von «Der Bestatter»: Doerig muss Anatol den Geschwistern Lara und Max ausliefern – sonst stirbt die gekidnappte Vanessa. Fabio verguckt sich in eine hübsche Pastorin. Und Luc sucht nach der Mutter von Lara und Max. Er muss sie finden, sonst droht Vanessa und Anatol der sichere Tod.",
  "description": "Schreckliches Erwachen für Polizist Reto Doerig: Seine Tochter Vanessa wurde von Lara und Max entführt. Jetzt soll Doerig Sozialarbeiter Anatol kidnappen und ihnen ausliefern. Dann wird er hingerichtet. Falls Doerig den Forderungen nicht nachkommt, wird Vanessa sterben. Über Handy und Knopf im Ohr erhält Doerig die Anweisungen, den unter Polizeischutz stehenden Anatol abzuholen. Doch mitten im Wald will der zunehmend misstrauische Anatol wissen, was gespielt wird. Beim anschliessenden Handgemenge geht Doerigs Handy kaputt und der Kontakt zu Vanessas Entführern bricht ab. Muss Vanessa jetzt sterben?\r\n\r\nDiese wird von Lara und Max in einem Bunker aus dem Zweiten Weltkrieg gefangen gehalten. Max quält das schlechte Gewissen, dass er seiner geliebten Vanessa diese Entführung antun musste. Er lockert ihre Fesseln. In einem unbeobachteten Moment kann Vanessa flüchten. Als Max dies entdeckt, fühlt er sich verraten. Ihn packt die blinde Wut und er jagt ihr nach. Hat Vanessa im Labyrinth des Bunkers überhaupt eine Chance, zu entkommen?\r\n\r\nWährend die Kantonspolizei Aargau das mörderische Geschwisterpaar jagt, muss sich Fabio um Anatols Tochter Maya kümmern. Dabei trifft Fabio die bildhübsche Pastorin Florence wieder, die ihm schöne Augen macht. Der junge Bestatter kümmert sich auch rührend um Maya. Was beide nicht wissen: Irgendwo in den Wäldern des Aargaus kämpft Mayas Vater Anatol um sein Leben.\r\n\r\nLuc glaubt, den Aufenthaltsort der Mutter von Lara und Max gefunden zu haben: auf einer einsamen Alp irgendwo in den Bergen. Doch als er dort ankommt, steht er vor verschlossenen Türen. Die Zeit rennt Luc Conrad davon. Wie wird es ihm trotzdem noch gelingen, den Fall zu lösen? Um zum letzten Mal Gerechtigkeit zu schaffen unter den Lebenden und den Toten.",
  "thumbnailUrl": "https://il.srgssr.ch/images/?imageUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fws.srf.ch%2Fasset%2Fimage%2Faudio%2F185d6878-4989-4bd4-a274-953986627752%2FEPISODE_IMAGE%2F1606398851.png&format=jpg&width=1920",
  "duration": "P0Y0M0DT1H0M8S",
  "url": "/tv/der-bestatter/video/phoenix-aus-der-asche-staffel-7-folge-6?urn=urn:srf:video:5da1d3d0-e445-447e-a67c-33dd10186f4c",
  "episodeNumber": 6,
  "partOfSeason": {
    "@type": "TVSeason",
    "seasonNumber": 7
  },
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "WatchAction",
    "target": {
      "@type": "EntryPoint",
      "urlTemplate": "/tv/der-bestatter/video/phoenix-aus-der-asche-staffel-7-folge-6?urn=urn:srf:video:5da1d3d0-e445-447e-a67c-33dd10186f4c",
      "inLanguage": "de",
      "actionPlatform": [
        "http://schema.org/DesktopWebPlatform",
        "http://schema.org/MobileWebPlatform",
        "http://schema.googleapis.com/GoogleVideoCast"
      ]
    },
    "actionAccessibilityRequirement": {
      "@type": "ActionAccessSpecification",
      "category": "nologinrequired"
    },
    "eligibleRegion": "EARTH"
  },
  "partOfSeries": {
    "@type": "TVSeries",
    "name": "Der Bestatter",
    "abstract": "Alle Folgen der Erfolgsserie mit Mike Müller als Luc Conrad.",
    "description": "Sehen Sie hier alle Folgen der Erfolgsserie mit Mike Müller als «Der Bestatter» Luc Conrad.\r\nLuc Conrad ist Bestatter aus Berufung. Trotzdem hilft der ehemalige Hauptkommissar der Polizei regelmässig bei der Aufklärung von Todesfällen.",
    "numberOfEpisodes": 40
  }
}
```

[image: Watch later feature]

Answer (score 0):

Your content has [poor performance](https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.srf.ch%2Fplay%2Ftv%2Fder-bestatter%2Fvideo%2Fphoenix-aus-der-asche-staffel-7-folge-6%3Furn%3Durn%3Asrf%3Avideo%3A5da1d3d0-e445-447e-a67c-33dd10186f4c) and a slow [download speed of about 35 seconds](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/230120_BiDcEY_95E/). This may be the reason for the Googlebot timeout. Critical Metrics Web Vitals is a negative signal for the [search rank](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2021/04/more-details-page-experience) of your content.

[Your structured data](https://validator.schema.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.srf.ch%2Fplay%2Ftv%2Fder-bestatter%2Fvideo%2Fphoenix-aus-der-asche-staffel-7-folge-6%3Furn%3Durn%3Asrf%3Avideo%3A5da1d3d0-e445-447e-a67c-33dd10186f4c) has 2 warnings. The [rich results](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result?id=ZOXzNDlwvYnim3qzPoXnvw) of your content have one warning.